# How to run selenium testscripts which are in maven project( - eclipse - java - and pushed to git -) on Jenkins which is hosted on a different machine

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-cli

I am having trouble for opening browsers :

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Is there any solution about it?

Comment: could you please provide us more information like your code block.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using desired capabilities to setup session?

This error appears only when we are using desired capabilities instead of ChrimeOptions.

It is mentioned in Selenium Release Notes that with the current implementation of Selenium while invoking RemoteWebDriver supports the ChromeOptions like

```
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://yourIP:5555/wd/hub"), options);
```

instead of `DesiredCapabilities` to make it works.

Additionally cross check firewall’s related issue on jenkins’s slave machine.

Chromedriver version should be v17.0.963.0 or after.

Hope it will help you.